# cucumber step undefine for http pattern

Tags: regex, cucumber, scenarios

Here is my feature:

```
Feature: Smoke tests  
  Scenario: Check status code of all links  
    Given I am logged in "https://myserver-product.domain.dom/"  
    When  I request every get route on the application  
    Then  I should see all the routes are reporting OK status code
```

Here are my steps:

```
Given(/^I am logged in "([^\"]*)"$/) do |base_url|
  # starting 
end

When(/^I request every get route on the application$/) do
 # do something 
end

Then(/^I should see all the routes are reporting OK status code$/) do
 # do something 
end
```

And finally, the cucumber report tells me that the scenario is undefined. I think the problem is the pattern `"([^\"]*)"` but I don't know why? I think it is correct. Any recomendations? I only need that cucumber pass the first step.

```
Feature: Smoke tests
  Scenario: Check status code of all links       
    Given I am logged in "https://myserver-product.domain.dom/"
    When I request every get route on the application
    Then I should see all the routes are reporting OK status code

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m0.002s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^I am logged in "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When(/^I request every get route on the application$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then(/^I should see all the routes are reporting OK status code$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

If you want snippets in a different programming language,
just make sure a file with the appropriate file extension
exists where cucumber looks for step definitions.
```

Comment: Are you sure you saved your steps `rb`?  I copied exactly what you have and mine is passing: `1 scenario (1 passed)`.

Comment: I find the solution in the accepted answer of [Cucumber not finding step definitions][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772970/cucumber-not-finding-step-definitions/25627072?noredirect=1#answer18773285